# Insert link box in wordpress does not appear

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to insert a link on a footer side bar (Appearance->Customize->Widgets->Footer Side Bar 1->Add Widget->Site Origin Editor)
I typed a word, highlighted it, and finally clicked on the link buttom, but the 'insert link' box does not pops up.
I am using the Esteem theme and firefox (but have also tried safari and it did not work neither)
Suggestions are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter this, but what I do is just a work around.
Add this 'a' tag in your code for the text to link.

```
<a href="yourlinkhere">your text here</a>
```